# How do we add information to an ask ubuntu webpage?

Tags: discussion, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can increase my reputation on AskUbuntu?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/495/how-can-increase-my-reputation-on-askubuntu)

This question should go in the meta section, I believe, but I am not yet able to post there.

I would like to find out how to go about gaining reputation. On the ask ubuntu webpage [here](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user) it tells you about reputation and the priviledges it permits you, but there is no link to how to go about gaining reputation.

I think the webpage should be updated to include a link to such information.

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly related to http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work

Comment: I don't mind you asking questions, but please have a look around before actually asking them, most of your issues and questions can be solved reading the FAQ and browsing the posts in meta. Also, it is not ok to ask to get upvotes.