# What is the best way to gain reputation?

Tags: discussion

I can't seem to do much except ask questions without having any reputation. It's almost like a catch 22, how do I get reputation if I can't vote or comment? I guess this is the best way right just to ask questions? Are there any other ways to gain reputation on here? I mean I can't even make my own tags yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers are not necessarily the same as comments. The best way to gain reputation is to answer existing questions concisely and with quality.

Linked by Mitch in one of the comments to your question, take a look at [How can I increase my reputation on AskUbuntu?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/495/how-can-i-increase-my-reputation-on-askubuntu) for any extra help.